# Handle PDF programatically: Read pixels to analyse the page and add graphics and text

Tags: pdf

### What I want to do

I want to add a textual stamp to PDF's. The stamp should be contained in a rectangle and placed in the least obtrusive location (LOL). The LOL will be calculated per PDF as they all are completely different.

1. `Input #PDF`: A PDF as consisting of one of multiple pages
2. `Input #Text`: A description text string of max 230 characters
3. Export the PDF to one image per page
4. Analyse the first page's image to see which areas are most suitable for writing the Text inside a clearly marked box (so it's obvious it's a "stamp" onto the page)
5. Write the Text inside a box onto the best place on the first page's image (the rest will not be touched)
6. Put together the PDF again
7. Print the PDF with the stamp and then throw it away

**Comments**

- I want to keep the document dimensions. I will most often recieve documents in the A4 format but it's preferable if it works for any format.
- The fact that I will rasterize some vector graphics and thus loose quality is not a big problem, as I don't actually want to keep the modified PDF files anyway. But I do not want them to loose quality in the printout, I guess going for 600 DPI should be enough?

### What I need help with

- I need help figuring out what to use for the actual conversion `PDF`>`Image`>`PDF`? It has to be free software which I can use in Ubuntu Linux.
- I don't *necessarily* need to take the route to an Image. But I do need a programmatic way to analyse the pixels and write text and graphics, so I thought it would be easiest.
- The programming language is not important. I'll make that choise depending on what has best APIs for this sort of thing. If I convert to an Image I'll probably use Python.

Comment: I can recommend iTextSharp, which I think can be used with Java and I know with C#; BTW, you do know that LOL is an overloaded acronym, right?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon: Thanks for the tip. I looked at iTextSharp but it seems more like an API to manipulate PDF, but to analyse where to but my text stamp i need to sweep over the pixels somehow. In other words, I need it to render the PDF for me and give me a way to analyse pixels. It does not seem to have that unfortunately.

And yeah. LOL is overloaded, but you guys can handle a little bit of overloading? ;)